# Trying to find users location in Xcode with Swift on starting the app but having optional error?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, mapkit, core-location

I'm attempting to have the app find the user's location once the app has been started. However, I continually find an error in the viewDidLoad method as I try to requestWhenInUseAuthorization and I receive the following error:

```
    fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value (lldb)
```

I would be really grateful if anyone could help me find a solution to this problem. Thanks!

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

var lastLocation = CLLocation()
var locationAuthorizationStatus:CLAuthorizationStatus!
var window: UIWindow?

let locationManager: CLLocationManager!

var seenError : Bool = false
var locationFixAchieved : Bool = false
var locationStatus : NSString = "Not Started"

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)


    self.initLocationManager()

}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()




    if (CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled()) {
        seenError = false
        locationFixAchieved = false

        locationManager = CLLocationManager()

        self.initLocationManager()

        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

    }



    mapView.showsUserLocation = true
    mapView.delegate = self
    self.mapView.setUserTrackingMode(MKUserTrackingMode.Follow, animated: true);

}

// Location Manager helper stuff
func initLocationManager() {


    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
}

// Location Manager Delegate stuff

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didFailWithError error: NSError!) {
    locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    if ((error) != nil) {
        if (seenError == false) {
            seenError = true
            print(error)
        }
    }
}



override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

Comment: Where do you assign an instance to your `locationManager` variable?

Comment: In viewDidLoad, why is `//locationManager = CLLocationManager()` commented out?  You need to do that first before using the locationManager variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your didload method is getting called before the didAppear method. Therefore, your location manager is not initialized yet. So you need to initialize it before using it.

Comment: So do I switch the didAppear method to be before the didLoad method?

Comment: And where do I state requestWhenInUseAuthorization?

Comment: But I tried this and I got an error: Trying to start MapKit location updates without prompting for location authorization. Must call -[CLLocationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization] or -[CLLocationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization] first.

Comment: override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        if (CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled()) {
            seenError = false
            locationFixAchieved = false
            
            locationManager = CLLocationManager()
            
            self.initLocationManager()
            
            locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
            
            locationManager.delegate = self
            locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
            
        }